# sed one-liner to delete any line that begins with a digit

Tags: sed, regular-expression

[image]

Pretend I am working with this file.

The beginning of the first visible line is obscured, so ignore that. 43 is the beginning of the next line, and that line would be deleted.

The next line (which begins with 44 and ends with a period) would be deleted.

The next line (which consists solely of 424) is also gone.

The next line (which consists of '11. King and Hero') is also gone.

The next line stays.

Comment: Rather than a screenshot, you should have copy-pasted the sample text as a code block. Think of blind readers!

Comment: @Gilles I would do that if there was a way to turn off syntax highlighting. (Is there?)

Comment: You mean the SE syntax highlighting? See [SO-specific markup - definitive resource?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79591#79591) and in particular [Interface options for specifying language prettify](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81970#81970): either use `<pre>` or put `<!--language: lang-none-->` just before the code block.

Comment: @Gilles Thanx. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sed -e '/^[0-9]/d' filename > filename.new
```

or to modify in place

```
sed -i -e '/^[0-9]/d' filename
```

Answer (score 10):

I'd use `grep(1)` for this:

```
grep -v '^[0-9]' filename
```

`^[0-9]` matches any line that begins with a digit, and `-v` excludes the lines that match, instead of including. You can also use the character class `[:digit:]` instead of `[0-9]`.

Instead of `-v` you can invert the range:

```
grep '^[^0-9]' filename
```

This will match any line that does not start with a digit, but it will not match blank lines.

With `grep`, `sed` and `awk`, my general rule is that for matching and simple extraction, use `grep`, for stateless re-writing, use `sed` and for stateful modifications, use `awk`. That is why I suggest using `grep` instead of `sed` as you asked in your question (and others have already answered for `sed`).

Comment: +1 since I agree this is more a grep work, no need to trouble with sed. I' like to know anyway which gives better performaces (that should matter)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/^[0-9].*$/d' oldfile > newfile
```